# Is there a way to make Doubles/Triple lines like in Word inside of HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to ask if there is a certain type of code that may give me double or triple lines in one code or would I have to create a separate code for each line.

This is what I would like to have.

[image: This is what I would like to have.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this is possible with CSS alone, but you could use two or three nested block elements, e.g. `<div>`s, with a small amount of padding between each. For example:

```css
.multi-border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-border">
    <div class="multi-border">
        <div class="multi-border">
            I am some example text!
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do some styling with borders. Check this out
[CSS Border Style](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution on the web for this. It looks like the action is here, but I will link to the source below.

```
.underline--double {
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -0.075em white,
    inset 0 -0.1em red,
    inset 0 -0.15em white,
    inset 0 -0.175em red;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use before and after for a class. By this you get maximum 3 border for a single class.

```
<div class="border">
   This is the code
</div>


.border {
   position:relative;
   border:5px solid #000;
   height:210px;
   width:210px;
   background: #f8f8f8;
   padding:30px;
   border-radius: 9px;
}
.border:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
  right:5px;
  border:5px solid #999;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

.border:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  bottom:15px;
  left:15px;
  right:15px;
  border:5px solid #666;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```